# Resampling, grouping, pivoting a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a log file with timestamps and two columns. I would now like to resample and "pivot" the dateframe created from the logfile.

Example orig dataframe/log file:

```
timestamp            colA  colB

2015-01-01 00:10:01   a     x
2014-01-01 00:10:01   b     y
2015-01-01 00:10:03   a     x
2015-01-01 00:10:03   a     x
2015-01-01 00:10:03   a     y
2015-01-01 00:10:04   b     x
2014-01-01 00:10:04   b     y
2014-01-01 00:10:04   b     y
2014-01-01 00:10:04   a     x
2014-01-01 00:10:05   a     x
2014-01-01 00:10:05   a     x
2014-01-01 00:10:07   a     y
2014-01-01 00:10:08   a     x
```

Example result for resampling by seconds:

```
                      a           b
timestamp             x     y     x     y

2015-01-01 00:10:01   1     0     0     1
2015-01-01 00:10:02   0     0     0     0
2015-01-01 00:10:03   2     1     0     0
2015-01-01 00:10:04   1     0     1     2
2014-01-01 00:10:05   2     0     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:06   0     0     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:07   0     1     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:08   1     0     0     0
```

How would I achieve this? Resample first, then groupby/pivot? Or the other way around? To be more specific I the cells should contain the count for colA/colB combinations for each specific resample timeintervall. In the example seconds, but it could be minutes, hours, etc.

I am not fixed on this format, I could also think of getting a result that is resampled and groupby timestamp/colA like

```
                             colB
timestamp              colA   x     y

2015-01-01 00:10:01     a     1     0
                        b     0     1
2015-01-01 00:10:02     a     0     0
                        b     0     0
2015-01-01 00:10:03     a     2     1
                        b     0     0
2015-01-01 00:10:04     a     1     0
                        b     1     2
2014-01-01 00:10:05     a     2     0
                        b     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:06     a     0     0
                        b     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:07     a     0     1
                        b     0     0
2014-01-01 00:10:08     a     1     0
                        b     0     0
```

The final usage would be to plot the different count values

THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0])
table = pd.crosstab(index=[df['timestamp']], columns=[df['colA'], df['colB']])
```

yields

```
colA                 a     b   
colB                 x  y  x  y
timestamp                      
2014-01-01 00:10:01  0  0  0  1
2014-01-01 00:10:04  1  0  0  2
2014-01-01 00:10:05  2  0  0  0
2014-01-01 00:10:07  0  1  0  0
2014-01-01 00:10:08  1  0  0  0
2015-01-01 00:10:01  1  0  0  0
2015-01-01 00:10:03  2  1  0  0
2015-01-01 00:10:04  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. How would one than access the different column groups for plotting? Automatically.

Comment: Maybe you don't have to, depending on the kind of plot you want to make. `table.plot(kind='bar', rot=25)` makes a bar plot, for example. Since this goes well beyond the scope of this question, and since it is the goal of the stackexchange community to create a *searchable* archive of good questions matched with good answers, try searching to see if your question is already answered, and if not, please post a new one.